# T4 template to generate relative path of solution files

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, t4

I need a T4 template or something else to integrate with Visual studio to generate relative path of files in solution.

Is their any add-ins or t4 to this?
I'm working with Visual studio 2012.

something like this:

```
    public static class Scripts
    {
        public static class AdminSkin
        {
            public static class Css
            {
                public const string Site = "/Scripts/adminskin/css/site.css";
                public const string SiteFa = "/Scripts/adminskin/css/site-fa.css"; 
                public const string Reset = "/Scripts/adminskin/css/reset.css";
                public const string SimpleList = "/Scripts/adminskin/css/simple-lists.css";
                public const string SpecialPages = "/Scripts/adminskin/css/special-pages.css";

            }

            public static class Js
            {
                public const string Site = "/Scripts/adminskin/js/site.js";
                public const string JqueryaccessibleList = "/Scripts/adminskin/js/jquery.accessibleList.js";
                public const string Jquerytip = "/Scripts/adminskin/js/jquery.tip.js";
                public const string List = "/Scripts/adminskin/js/list.js";
                public const string Oldbrowsers = "/Scripts/adminskin/js/old-browsers.js";
                public const string LiveControl = "/Scripts/adminskin/js/live-control.js";
            }
        }

        public static class Calendar
        {
            public static class Js
            {
                public const string Calendar = "/Scripts/calendar/calendar.js";
                public const string CalendarSetup = "/Scripts/calendar/calendar-setup.js";

                public const string CalendarFa = "/Scripts/calendar/calendar-fa.js";
                public const string CalendarEn = "/Scripts/calendar/calendar-en.js";
            }

            public static class Css
            {
                public const string Theme = "/Scripts/calendar/aqua/theme.css";
            }
        }

        public static class HighChart
        {
            public static class Js
            {
                public const string Highstock = "/Scripts/highchart/highstock.js";
                public const string HighstockModified = "/Scripts/highchart/highstock.src.js";
                public const string Theme = "/Scripts/highchart/themes/mytheme.js";
                public const string Exporting = "/Scripts/highchart/modules/exporting.src.js";
            }
        }

        public static class ImageGallery
        {
            public static class Js
            {
                public const string JqueryEasing = "/Scripts/ImageGallery/js/jquery.easing.1.3.min.js";
                public const string JqueryWtRotator = "/Scripts/ImageGallery/js/jquery.wt-rotator.min.js";
                public const string Preview = "/Scripts/ImageGallery/js/preview.js";
            }

            public static class Css
            {
                public const string Preview = "/Scripts/ImageGallery/preview.css";
                public const string JqueryWtRotator = "/Scripts/ImageGallery/wt-rotator.css";
            }
        }

        public static class JQuery
        {
            public static class Js
            {
                public const string JqueryCdn = "http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.2.min.js ";
                public const string JqueryUiCdn = "http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.20/jquery-ui.min.js";
                public const string JqueryUiCssCdn = "http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.20/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css";

                public const string JqueryLocal = "/Scripts/jquery/jquery-1.7.min.js";
                public const string JqueryUiLocal = "/Scripts/jquery-ui/js/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.min.js";
                public const string JqueryUiCssLocal = "/Scripts/jquery-ui/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.css";
            }
        }

        public static class Linq
        {
            public static class Js
            {
                public const string Linq = "/Scripts/linq.js/linq.min.js";
            }
        }


        public static class Moment
        {
            public static class Js
            {
                public const string Moment = "/Scripts/moment/moment.min.js";
            }
        }

        public static class Lang
        {
            public static class Js
            {
                public const string Jalali = "/Scripts/lang/jalali.js";
                public const string LangFa = "/Scripts/lang/lang-fa.js";
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: @podiluska: Because my web app has very js, css and page (html, .aspx) files and I've referenced theme in multiple places. so i want a way that files address of solution are generated to class and refnce them by class properties. this guaranties that when ever a file are moved, it's path updated in class and whenever a file deleted a compile time error occur if I've referenced it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[T4MVC](http://t4mvc.codeplex.com/) might be what you are looking for. It is a [T4 template for ASP.NET MVC apps](http://t4mvc.codeplex.com/documentation) that will create strongly typed helpers. It will generate a set of classes that you can use instead of using strings. For static files such as javascript files there will be a set of classes such as:

```
Links.Scripts.jquery_validate_js
```

This will return a string of the form "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js".

For a WebForms project [David Ebbo created a simple T4 template](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidebb/archive/2009/07/12/asppathguru-a-little-t4-love-for-asp-net-webforms.aspx) called AspPathGuru.tt. This currently only supports .aspx, .ascx and .master files. However if you edit the IgnoreFile method, as shown below, you can generate code for other files:

```
bool IgnoreFile(FileInfo file) {
    // Only look for a few specific extensions
    switch (file.Extension.ToLowerInvariant()) {
        case ".aspx":
        case ".ascx":
        case ".js":
        case ".css":
        case ".master":
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

This will generate a Paths class you can use as shown below:

```
Paths.Scripts.jquery_1_4_1_js
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I'm using asp.net web forms not asp.net mvc. I've installed T4MVC via nuget and after compilation i get system.mvc refrence not found error

Comment: David Ebbo did create a simple T4 template for web forms project. I will update the answer.